# tor v3.x in xenial?

Tags: configuration, ubuntu, update, binaries

just saw the latest posts on the torproject blog, i see tor v3.x is out, but after running apt-get update there isn't a tor update?

```
> apt-cache policy tor
tor:
  Installed: 0.2.9.10-1~xenial+1
  Candidate: 0.2.9.10-1~xenial+1
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.9.10-1~xenial+1 1001
       1001 tor+http://sdscoq7snqtznauu.onion/torproject.org xenial/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.2.7.6-1ubuntu1 500
    500 tor+http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

when i view the repo in the browser i can see there was an update on the 26th:

http://sdscoq7snqtznauu.onion/torproject.org/dists/xenial/main/

am i missing something? why isn't v3 an update candidate?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it:

- `0.2.9.10` is the current stable release and will be what remains in stable releases.
- `0.3.x` is the new stable and will be what it is included in the next stable Debian release (`stretch`) when it moves from `testing` to `stable`.

I wouldn't expect to see it hit Ubuntu or Debian repos until `strech` becomes `stable` and `jessie` becomes `oldstable`.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Just seems unusual, normally when they announce updates like that on their blog, there's an update waiting for me. Thanks again, really appreciate your contributions to tor.stack

Comment: I don't have direct quotes for it because I don't keep logs but the above is what I took away from what Roger told a user who asked the same question in `#tor` on IRC.